# Order sublist within a list depending on some characters

Tags: python, regex, list

Hel lo I need some help in order to order sublist within a list depending on some characters

here is an exemple:

I have a list :

```
List
[['QANH01000554.1_32467-32587_+__Sp_1', 'QANH01000554.1_32371-32464_+__Sp_1'], ['QANH01000809.1_27675-27794_-__Sp_1', 'QANH01000809.1_27798-27890_-__Sp_1']]
```

and I would like to get :

```
[['QANH01000554.1_32467-32587_+__Sp_1', 'QANH01000554.1_32371-32464_+__Sp_1'], [ 'QANH01000809.1_27798-27890_-__Sp_1','QANH01000809.1_27675-27794_-__Sp_1']]
```

So I would like to iterate over each sublist and if there is a `-`, then I would like to sort the sublist with `[\d]+[-]+[\d]` (the first [\d] being the highest)

As you can se in the sublist

```
['QANH01000809.1_27675-27794_-__Sp_1', 'QANH01000809.1_27798-27890_-__Sp_1']
```

`27798 > 27675` so I changed to

```
['QANH01000809.1_27798-27890_-__Sp_1','QANH01000809.1_27675-27794_-__Sp_1']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `sorted` with a custom key.

**Ex:**

```
import re  
data = [['QANH01000554.1_32467-32587_+__Sp_1', 'QANH01000554.1_32371-32464_+__Sp_1'], ['QANH01000809.1_27675-27794_-__Sp_1', 'QANH01000809.1_27798-27890_-__Sp_1']]
print([sorted(i, key=lambda x: tuple(int(n) for n in re.search(r"(\d+)\-(\d+)", x).groups()), reverse=True) for i in data])
```

**Output:**

```
[['QANH01000554.1_32467-32587_+__Sp_1', 'QANH01000554.1_32371-32464_+__Sp_1'], ['QANH01000809.1_27798-27890_-__Sp_1', 'QANH01000809.1_27675-27794_-__Sp_1']]
```